# Angular & RxJS Duplicate Code with subscriptions - moving the code to a service, types and unsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some duplicate code in a couple of my components... I have simplified the code but it basically is this collection of lines:

```
// code in my components
phoneNumberChanges$: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    // watch the phone number
    this.subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges();
}


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.phoneNumberChanges$) {
      this.phoneNumberChanges$.unsubscribe();
    }
}

subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges(): void {
    const phoneNumberControl = this.addPhoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'];
    this.phoneNumberChanges$ = phoneNumberControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(0))
      .subscribe((phoneNumber) => {
        if (phoneNumber.length < 5 || phoneNumber.charAt(0) !== '+') {
          // set the error message
          // set the form control to invalid
          phoneNumberControl.setErrors({ invalid: true });
        } else if (phoneNumberControl.errors && phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid) {
          delete phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid;
        }
      });
  }
```

now as I use this in different components, the only difference this code has between the components is the reference to the form. So I was thinking that I could move this to a service file and pass the form as an argument, so in my service file I could have something like this

```
// service file
subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges(parentForm: FormGroup): any {
    const phoneNumberControl = parentForm.controls['phoneNumber'];
    return phoneNumberControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(0))
      .subscribe((phoneNumber) => {
        if (phoneNumber.length < 5 || phoneNumber.charAt(0) !== '+') {
          // set the error message
          // set the form control to invalid
          phoneNumberControl.setErrors({ invalid: true });
        } else if (phoneNumberControl.errors && phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid) {
          delete phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid;
        }
      });
  }
```

then in my original component I could call the service method

```
// component file
ngOnInit(): void {
    // watch the phone number
    this.phoneNumberChanges$ = this.subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges();
}
```

this seems to work but I have three questions...

1. In my component file what type should I give my property `phoneNumberChanges$`?
2. what is the return type of my service method, I can't just return any?
   `subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges(parentForm. FormGroup): any`
3. Should I put the unsubscribe in my component or the service file?

Do I keep this in the component file

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.phoneNumberChanges$) {
      this.phoneNumberChanges$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

or add something to the service file? I am assuming the component file due to the lifecycle hook?

many thanks in advance, sorry about such silly questions and if I have not explained myself well please say so and I shall rework my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr;**

1. `Observable<any>`
2. `Observable<any>`
3. Component File

I would let the component do the subscription. Otherwise you cannot add custom logic (like more operators) to your osbervable, without subscribing a secound time. Its good practice to do it like this since observables are lazy and the caller can decide when he wants to subscribe. Change your service method to this:

```
  subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges(parentForm: FormGroup): Observable<any> {
    const phoneNumberControl = parentForm.controls["phoneNumber"];
    return phoneNumberControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(0),
      tap(phoneNumber => {
        if (phoneNumber.length < 5 || phoneNumber.charAt(0) !== "+") {
          // set the error message
          // set the form control to invalid
          phoneNumberControl.setErrors({ invalid: true });
        } else if (
          phoneNumberControl.errors &&
          phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid
        ) {
          delete phoneNumberControl.errors.invalid;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

And its also a good idea to let the component handle the unsubscribe, since the component is aware of its lifecycle. The code can look like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.phoneNumberChanges$ = this.service.subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges();
    this.subscription = this.phoneNumberChanges$.subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Or my preferred way is to create a destroy notifier observable:

```
 private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.phoneNumberChanges$ = this.service.subscribeToPhoneNumberChanges();
    this.phoneNumberChanges$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

Another possibility would be to pass a `notifier` Observable to the service method and add the `takeUntil` operator there.